# Network byte order - telegram

Tags: java, networking

Good morning

I am writing an application that need to communicate to a Verifone vx820 ped via ATS software.

In their documentation, to transmit data, it states:

[image: transmitting data]

I have an example in c# in how to do it, which is here:

```
// Format of ATS telegram:
            //
            //       +---------------------------- ... ---------------------------------+
            //       | xx | xx | xx | xx | Data                                         |
            //       +---------------------------- ... ---------------------------------+
            // Byte  |  0 |  1 |  2 |  3 | 4       ... 
            //       |                   |
            // Field | -- Data Length -- | Data
            //
            // Data length is 4 bytes; network byte order (big-endian)

            try
            {
                // Attempt to make TCP connection to ATS
                Connect();

                // Convert data length to network byte order...
                int iLengthNetworkByteOrder = IPAddress.HostToNetworkOrder(Data.Length);

                // ...then convert it to a byte array
                byte[] DataLength = BitConverter.GetBytes(iLengthNetworkByteOrder);

                // Construct the send buffer, prefixing the data with the data length as shown above
                m_SendBuffer = new byte[DataLength.Length + Data.Length];
                DataLength.CopyTo(m_SendBuffer, 0);
                Data.CopyTo(m_SendBuffer, DataLength.Length);

                // Signal the background thread there is data to send
                m_eventSendDataAvailable.Set();
            }
```

However I am building this is java. Could anyone help me in the conversion to Java. Are there easy methods in Java to do this?

Has anyone built an application which uses ATS with java, is there anything useful I should know

Comment: The primitive-writing methods of `DataOutputStream` are all big-endian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  Java, you have the fantastic [`ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html) class that lets you encode / decode ordinary values (integers, floats, doubles) into / from bytes. `ByteBuffer` lets you specify the used endianness through its [`order(ByteOrder)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/ByteBuffer.html#order(java.nio.ByteOrder)) method.

So, let's say you have a `byte[] data` that you want to prepend with a length in 32-bit big endian, as in your example. You'd write:

```
// Create a buffer where we'll put the data to send
ByteBuffer sendBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(4 + data.length);
sendBuffer.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN); // it's the default, but included for clarity

// Put the 4-byte length, then the data itself
sendBuffer.putInt(data.length);
sendBuffer.put(data);

// Extract the actual bytes from our sendBuffer
byte[] dataToSend = sendBuffer.array();
```

If you had the reverse case (ATS sending you data with a prefixed length), the code would be very similar but with `getInt` and `get` instead.

Comment: @ jmendeth Tried running this this morning, however its still not working. When I debug it, I can see the dataToSend array, and the first 4 bytes read 0, 0, 1, -43. In the documentation it looks like they are assigning the hex values, so for example, a message of 469 bytes would have the hex of 1d5, which I would need to assign the first 4 characters to 00, 00, 01, d5.

Am I missing something

Comment: No, it's all correct. You expect 00, 00, 01, D5. In decimal, this is 0, 0, 1, 213. However, bytes are *signed* numbers in Java so the byte 213 is represented by a -43 (213 converted to signed is -43).

Comment: @JamesKing Resuming: the code produces the bytes you said.